# Using an If/Else statement in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to use an if/else statement in my Java FX program but it keeps giving me the "else" output even if the "if" statement is met. I checked my onaction events and my fx ids just to make sure they were corresponding.

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;



public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Label user;
    @FXML
    private Label pass;
    @FXML
    public Button button;
    @FXML
    public TextField username;
    @FXML
    public TextField password;
    @FXML
    public void doSomething(){
        if ((username.equals("John")) && (password.equals("Doe"))) {
            System.out.println("Welcome");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Please Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="20" vgap="10">
    <Label text="Username" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" fx:id="user"/><TextField GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" fx:id="username"/>
    <Label text="Password" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" fx:id="pass"/><TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" fx:id="password"/>
    <Button text="Login" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" fx:id="button" onAction="#doSomething"/>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: JavaFX Script is officially discontinued, just do your JavaFX stuff in normal Java. Just saying.

Comment: @ChrisDennett there is no JavaFX script in this question.

Comment: Do you use just pure java now for yours?

Comment: @Charles You should continue to use FXML for the layout and Java for the logical control, as you are doing in this post. JavaFX script was part of JavaFX 1 and is discontinued, and no longer supported. I don't know why the other commenter is referring to it here as it is not relevant to anything you have posted.

Comment: Gotcha @James_D. Thanks for informing me. I will continue.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I'm not familar with JavaFX, so I assumed that it was JavaFX Script. Not my finest hour ;)

Comment: Its all good @ChrisDennett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `username.equals()` and `password.equals()` use

`username.getText().equals()` and `password.getText().equals()`

that will give the String value of the TextArea's

Comment: Also consider `PasswordField`.

Comment: No problem! Glad i could help.

Comment: You're right @trashgod I was gonna change it in a bit. was just laying down the foundation. Good looking out.